# Akka.NET message integrity

Tags: akka.net

I could not find the answer in the documentation, thus i'm asking it here.
Does Akka.NET guarantee the integrity of the messages ? or do i need to implement my own md5 hash for each message ? 
I plan to transfer images of 100Kb in size each between the actors. So it is imperative that the actors receive them in totality.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not received as a stream. The message is received through the wire and later deserialized completely. In code you will get the complete message.

Comment: Worth reading :)
https://petabridge.com/blog/large-messages-and-sockets-in-akkadotnet/